# dispatch redux action only if a previous action has success

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

the situation is as follows: I need to call some API endpoints passing an auth token I previously requested. The problem is this token can expire, so each time I want to call an endpoint to retrieve data I need to ensure the token is valid and renew if necessary.

Currently I have an async action that renews the token and another set of actions that retrieves data from API.

My goal is to make some kind of aspect-programming/composition of both actions, like:

`renewTokenIfNeeded = ... // action that check if token has expired and renew it
getData = ...            // Retrieves data from API
realGetData = compose(renewTokenIfNeeded, getData);`

The idea is `realGetData` action checks if token is expired, calling the `renewTokenIfNeeded` and only if this action success then call the `getData`.

Is there any pattern for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an action that returns a function instead of an object and use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware. Actions that return a function are not pure and you can make more function calls and perform multiple dispatches within the action. So, it could look something like:

```
getData = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await renewTokenIfNeeded()
  getData()
  // Any dispatches you may want to do 
}
```

Make sure you add the `redux-thunk` middleware to your store as mentioned in the documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [redux thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or any other middleware (e.g redux saga) to solve the token issue. Redux thunk lets action creators return a function instead of an action.

```
export function checkTokenValidity(token) {
  return (dispatch) => {
          dispatch(TOKEN_CHECK_REQUEST());
    return (AsyncAPICall)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch(TOKEN_CHECK_SUCCESS(response.data));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
}

export function getData(id) {
      return (dispatch) => {
              dispatch(GETDATA_REQUEST());
        return (AsyncAPICall(id))
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch(GETDATA_SUCCESS(response.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      };
    }

export function checkTokenAndGetData(token,id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
     dispatch(checkTokenValidity(token)).then(() => {
       dispatch(getData(id));
     });
  };
}
```

The problem with this approach is that code gets messy easily as you have to combine the checking of Token and an arbitrary API call every time.

This is a little better.

(2) (If you like to call it in your action creator for state tracking) Pass the token in the request, have a middleware to intercept the request and change the response to "Invalid Token/Expired Token", or the real data to have a clean and readable frontend code.

```
export function getData(token,id) {
      return (dispatch) => {
              dispatch(GETDATA_REQUEST());
        return (AsyncAPICall(id))
        .then((response) => {
           //if response is EXPIRED token
           dispatch(renewToken()); // renew token is another action creator
           //else
          dispatch(GETDATA_SUCCESS(response.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      };
    }
```

My suggestion, is to move your token validation in your backend.

(3)Always pass the token in the request, have a middleware to intercept the request, if it is expired, renew it in the backend code. Add an identifier to your response that it was expired and renewed it. Much simpler.